# XML Parse Error on a big file when importing into Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I'm getting a Parse Error when trying to import the XML file unzipped from discogs_20170701_releases.xml.gz from the website http://data.discogs.com/?prefix=data/2017/.

The file is too big to be checked manually. Is there a way around this in order to be able to access the information in Excel?